# What should go into the model and the view-model?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, mvvm, wcf-client

I'm developing a WPF Client which interacts with a WCF Web Service which persists data on a database using NHibernate.

The client will use the MVVM design pattern for the UI and interacts with the WCF Service by sending and receiving DTOs.

From what I understand, only presentation data and logic should go in the View-Model, whereas the Model should contain the application's data and business logic.

Now let's use for example the case of a Login screen in the Client.

- The View will represent the Login screen itself and its data context will be the View-Model.
- The View-Model will hold an instance of the Model and will update the View by implementing the INotifyProperty interface.

Here's my question: what exactly should go in the Model ?

Should it hold a reference to an interface of a WCF proxy using a dependency injection container such as MEF ?

Basically, the user would type in a username and password, which would update the properties in the view-model due to the databinding. Whenever the user presses the "Login" button on the view, a command is sent to the View-Model which in turn forwards it to the Model. The model then uses the Proxy interface to communicate with the WCF Web Service.

Is this approach correct ? If not, what exactly should go in the Model and View-Model?

Comment: Why does the View-Model get an instance of the view?

Comment: Should the view get an instance of the VM instead..? I've seen many implementations of the MVVM pattern and either the VM has an instance of the View, or vice-versa. How would you go about implementing the pattern ? In other words, should I create the View and inject the VM, or should I create the VM and inject the View ?

Comment: The view has the View-Model as DataContext. So the View knows about the ViewModel. Usually you don't need to know the View from ViewModel. If the ViewModel gets an instance of the View, you might have a tight coupling

Comment: Understood, thanks. So creating a new instance of the view and displaying it would also create an instance of the View-Model due to it being the data context. Should the View-Model hold an instance of the Model ?

Comment: hope this helps. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/08/15/fundamental-mvvm.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewModel in MVVM is a combination of the ApplicationModel and Controller in [classic MVC](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2008/06/mvc-model-view-controller-design.html). As such it is responsible for connecting to services to query for data to display and invoke operations against the service.

The workflow should be something like this:

1. LoginViewModel is created and gets a handle to the WCF service (ideally, you should use DI to inject the WCF service as an ILoginService)
2. User enters username and password which are bound to corresponding properties on the VM and clicks login which is bound to a delegate command on the VM.
3. Within the command handler the VM runs validation (e.g. make sure that username and password have been set)
4. The VM invokes LoginUser on the ILoginService passing the username and password (invoking the operation on the WCF service.

The model shouldn't be aware of services and the like. Technically, you are using pure DTOs on the client side so it should have minimal logic, behind the service, there should be a richer model that does have business logic and validation.

Comment: "The ViewModel in MVVM is a combination of the ApplicationModel and Controller in classic MVC" +1 - that is a great way to summarise.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [Karls Shiffletts blog](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/learning-wpf-m-v-vm/) you'll find a good diagram about the MVVM-Layers.
I would say your implementation looks okay to me.

It depends on you implementation, most propably you will switch the ViewModel and have a DataTemplate (the View) for the ViewModel. This CodeProject link shows a good implementation: [Creating an Internationalized Wizard in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx)

Comment: The diagram is a great one, but I disagree about the current implementation being OK. The suggestion of accessing the WCF service through your `Model` is a bad idea. Access to the WCF service should go through the `ViewModel`, not the `Model`

Comment: Thanks for the links WaltiD, I also like the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

`Models` should not contain data access or any business logic beyond validating their data. They are data objects, and should contain nothing more than data and validation.

Your `ViewModels` are in charge of running your application, and this includes filling the data objects (Models), altering them, saving/deleting them, and providing them (and other related properties) to the `View`.

I have a simple MVVM example [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) if you're interested. There is a definition at the very top that defines what should go into the `Model` compared to the `ViewModel`

Comment: Thanks Rachel, that's exactly what I wanted to know. I'll take a look at your example. Just wondering, would the View Model fetch the data from the Model, convert it in a format that can be sent to the Web Service and then call the Web Service ?

Comment: @Hussein Yes. Sometimes my Model is the object that the WCF service returns, and other times I use something like `AutoMapper` to map a `Model` into a `DTO` and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, I'm starting to grasp the concepts. As for the Login Screen example in my initial post, I believe I'll go this route: The View's DataContext will be the View Model. Whenever the user presses the "Connect" button on the View, a command is used to call the View Model, which in turn will create a DTO (i.e.: Model) with the parameters received by the command. The View Model will then proceed to contact the Web Service. In the event that the Web Service returns an error, the View Model will alert the View by updating a property the View is bound to.